# Reducing a List of size 1

Tags: scala, reduce

```
scala> List(5) reduceLeft { (z, f) => z + f }
res1: Int = 5
```

How does this work? What does scala provide for the value of `z` when performing `z + f` in this case?

Comment: [Read the documentation first](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List) and then see [Fold on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)). Include the information "discovered" in the documentation and use it for refinement, if/as the question remains.

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks for the snark. I *did* read the documentation for `reduceLeft`, did you? It specifically does not say what happens in the case of a `List` of size 1. Nor does it make any reference to `fold` for further research. "RTFM" is hardly an appropriate response here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
override /*TraversableLike*/
def reduceLeft[B >: A](f: (B, A) => B): B =
  if (isEmpty) throw new UnsupportedOperationException("empty.reduceLeft")
  else tail.foldLeft[B](head)(f)
```

As you can see `reduceLeft` is implemented in terms of `foldLeft` and the latter is allowed on empty list, it simply returns the starting element (which in your case is 5):

```
override /*TraversableLike*/
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B = {
  var acc = z
  var these = this
  while (!these.isEmpty) {
    acc = f(acc, these.head)
    these = these.tail
  }
  acc
}
```

So basically `acc` is returned.

Comment: Thanks! Is that the actual source for `reduceLeft` then, or just an example of how it could be implemented?

Comment: @CoryKlein It's the actual source you can find in [LinearSeqOptimized](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/5e0880fe05fb65a8757721be7e5be6a3259c19a8/src/library/scala/collection/LinearSeqOptimized.scala), note that for collection operations it doesn't matter the lenght of the list (if it's not empty).

Answer (score 1):

`reduceLeft` takes the first value of the list as the initial value. If there are no more elements, it returns that.